# How to perform an event on Textbox focus in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three textboxes A, B and C in "CreateUser" view. When user enters some text in textbox A and B, and then when he enters textbox C, I want to display the text of textbox A + text of textbox B in C with "-" in between.

For example, 
He enters "ABC" in `textBox A` and then he enters "123" in `textBox B`. Now upon entering `textBox C` (focus event), I want to display "ABC - 123 - " in textBox C. "-" are added through code.

How do I do that in MVC ?

Comment: In this case... MVC has little to do... the KEY here is Javascript, in order to do this in client side... and achieve the intended behavior.

Comment: You can do it with jQuery. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Romias I have no experience with JavaScript unfortunately or JQuery for that matter. I have started MVC yesterday.

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer If you are going to do MVC, you will need to know HTML and Javascript VERY well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. Your Razor view as follows

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "txtA" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "txtB" })
@Html.TextBox("TextBoxC", "Focus to list value", new { @class = "txtC" })
```

And your JavaScript and jquery code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
      $('.txtC').on('focus', function () {
          $(this).val($('.txtA').val() + " - " + $('.txtB').val());
      });
  });
</script>
```

Make sure your model includes the bound fields and you reference the jquery file in the application or through CDN.

Comment: I tried this carefully but still unfortunately nothing happened when I focused textBox C. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
  // do stuff here
  }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

Comment: I have used @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text). How do I call Javascript on this ?

Comment: In this case you do: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text, new {onfocus = "myFunction()"})

Answer (score 0):

Do it through JavaScript, or in controller class that receives your text-data in custom model, modifies it like you want and send back the to the same view.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know how to write JavaScript. I guess, I will have to learn JS or JQuery first.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get started, take the time and learn Javascript and jQuery. (jQuery is an extension of JavaScript that makes some things easier, and makes the browsers behaves more similarly.)

If you use jQuery, here's the code that you'll need:

HTML:

```
// The "new { id = "text" }" is an anonymous object that 
// will contain the HTML attributes
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text, new { id = "text" })
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doStuff = function () {
        // Whatever you need it to do.
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#text').on('focus', function() {
            doStuff();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: A good book to use to learn about JavaScript and jQuery would be Pro jQuery 2.0 by Adam Freeman.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will definitely read this book. But for now, can you please tell me how to pick textbox value in javascript?

Comment: `$('#text').attr('value')` in jQuery or `document.getElementById("text").value` using pure JavaScript.